# document.createElement not working how I want it to

Tags: javascript

I don't know how to put things in code on this website, But I am new to Javascript and I am trying to make a simple little script that allows me to press submit and post messages.

It's not working, I think it has something to do with the `<form>` tag and `document.createElement`

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <title>This stuff</title> 
    <head> 
        <style> 
        div.postbox {
            position:fixed;
            top:500px;
        } 
        </style>
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <div id="messages"> </div> 
        <div class="postbox"> 
            <form> 
                <input type="text" id="messagecontent"> 
                <button onclick="post()">submit </button> 
            </form> 
        </div> 
        <script> 
            function post() { 
                var chats = document.getElementById("messages"); 
                var val = document.getElementById("messagecontent").value; 
                var post = document.createElement("div");
                post.textContent = val; 
                chats.appendChild(post); 
            }
        </script> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

Here it is in **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VJcNu/)**.

Comment: The form is posted, so whatever you do, will not be visible, because the page is reloaded.

Comment: have a look here http://jsfiddle.net/avmCX/46/

Comment: How do I make it so the page doesn't reload and I can visibly see it?

Comment: Use `<button type="button"...>` since a button with no type is, by default, a submit button.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why use a form if you don't use it? If you don't have to reload the page, just remove the form tags. My HTML would be something like:

```
<div id="messages"></div>

<div class="postbox">
   <input type="text" id="messagecontent"> 
   <button onclick="post()">submit </button> 
</div>
```

In the JS, I would use innerHTML to set the

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   function post()
   {
      //get the messages div
      var chats = document.getElementById("messages");    
      //get the textbox value
      var val = document.getElementById("messagecontent").value;
      //add the textbox value into the messages div
      chats.innerHTML += val + '<br />';
   }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use

```
 <button type="button onclick="post()">submit </button>
```

Form is submitted because type is not specified and by default it's a submit button.

As it's in 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button

"The button submits the form data to the server. This is the default if the attribute is not specified, or if the attribute is dynamically changed to an empty or invalid value."

Answer (score 0):

Your fiddle can't work because you put the code into the `onLoad` event (you can see it in the combobox on the left). So the `post` function isn't global and can't be called.

Concerning the code itself :

- It's recommended to put the function into the head
- I think using a form is a good idea (even if you don't send anything to the server), but only if you replace the button with a submit. That will (for example) allow you to send the message by using `ENTER` instead of clicking the button.

To do that, you don't have to detect the click, but the form validation instead. And cancel this validation, so nothing is sent to the server

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <title>This stuff</title>
    <head>
        <style>
            div.postbox {
                position:fixed;
                top:500px;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            function post() {
                var chats = document.getElementById("messages");
                var val = document.getElementById("messagecontent").value;
                var post = document.createElement("div");
                post.textContent = val;
                chats.appendChild(post);

                // Returning false is important in order to cancel the form validation!
                return false;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="messages"> </div>
        <div class="postbox">
            <form onsubmit="return post();">
                <input type="text" id="messagecontent">
                <input type="submit" value="Add message" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```